# How do you implement a programming environment in a workplace?

Tags: java

There are currently no development tools in the environment I work in.  I am the only developer in the working environment.  What are guidelines in implementing a programming/development working environment? (Example, what do I need to do, in order for me to create internal java applications, which may include tools, licenses, etc.)

Comment: This is quite off-topic. I hope you will read the answer before it gets flagged and moved.

Answer (score 0):

As you are the only developer in your environment, there are a few things that are fortunate. You tagged this question with Java, so I will assume you want to work with this language.

- Java itself, if not already installed. You can find Java at their [website](https://www.java.com/en), and download the latest version on it on your machine. This will allow you to launch your Java applications outside the IDE (next point). To check if you have installed it, it is usually under your `Program Files` folder, most often: `C:/Program Files/Java`.
- An [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (Integrated development environment). There are a lot of them, but the most famous might be [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/). It often comes with an embedded Java version with it.

And that's it. Only the IDE would work pretty well. In pure theory, you could even do it with Java only and its compiler, but pretty much every Java developer uses an IDE. Licencing is an internal thing that you will need to implement.

---

By the way, I will let you read this, and flag it in five minutes. It should not be there. You should try [Programmers' Stack platform](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of topic, which is not related to pure programming.

Comment: Thank you, should I remove this question and repost in Programmers' Stack platform?  I guess my question was more specific to licenses.

Comment: You shall move this question to Programmers' Stack. About the licencing tools, you could ask here something like "How to implement licencing easily". Do not forget, here we ask specific questions and get specific answers. Be really clear and neat about what you want, about **programming some licencing software or use an existing one**.